# In Unity is a WWW class asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand how to write a WWW call in Unity.  According to the description here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html I can inspect the isDone property, but in the example on the same page, it makes no attempt to inspect isDone.

The question I have is, if I make a WWW call and it takes several seconds to reply, doesn't the game freeze?

I would like to think the right code is this, but is it?

```
StartCoroutine(WaitForResponse(myWWWObject));

private IEnumerator WaitForResponse(WWW aRequest ) {

    while ( ! aRequest.isDone )
        yield return aRequest;

}
```

Does the game freeze until aRequest is done?  Or is it truly asynchronous?

Comment: From the example, I'm guessing that the `yield return www;` line asynchronously waits until the page is downloaded.

Comment: in that example it just waits until the www requests finishes (waiting happens in line "yield return www;"). 

You can also use this new webrequest for more control: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

Comment: How does it know it's complete if the return is IEnumerator ... there is nothing to "test" for completion

Comment: It appears that my code above will work expect that it's overkill; but only by a bit.  The IsDone is for testing the WWW completion on the main thread where as the yield is for a coroutine.  The yield stalls the thread until an answer comes back, either as a success or failure.  So in a coroutine, the loop will have one iteration in a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand Coroutines - a fundamental feature of Unity that allows you to write long-duration code functions (eg: longer then a frame) that will *not* freeze your game.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

In C# you can spot a coroutine function because it has a return type of `IEnumerator`. And you can spot the locations in the code where the function will suspend and continue from again by the C# keyword `yield`.

Each MonoBehaviour class can manage coroutines, and if you tell it to start one with StartCoroutine(), then MonoBehaviour will call the coroutine every frame (sometimes more then once) until the Coroutine reaches the end.

For WWW class (which supports co-routines), all you need is to call this:

```
  WWW www = new WWW(url);
  yield return www;
```

You create a WWW class with the URL to retrievve, and the yield will basically be called each frame automatically by the MonoDevelop coroutine manager until www object says it has completed (successfully or failure).

Your game will not freeze at all during this time.

Comment: It sounds to me that the thread is the thing that freezes and since it's a coroutine, it's not going to impact your main process.  Only that your main process has to know that the thread is locked and manage it (ie shut it down if necessary; such as a stop all coroutines).

Comment: Coroutines run in the main thread - which is the key reason for them - that you don't need to worry about multi-threading. A coroutine should be designed to do a lot of little work and then give up the cpu via yield. Perfect for downloading a file. For heavy computation where you can't easily yield then threads are still the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the linked documentation page for [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html), the following method is a coroutine method:

```
IEnumerator Start() {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

The yield statement is used to pause execution and return control to Unity and then to resume execution in the next game frame. For example `yield return null;` will cause execution to resume in the next frame. Additionally, you can extend that behaviour by using one of the classes that derive from YieldInstruction class, for example [WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html).

Consider `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);` - this will resume execution after 1 second of game time has passed. The WWW class works in similar way. You can use an instance of that class to yield execution, returning only after the download has been completed, no need to manually poll the `isDone` property.

Keep in mind that you can only yield in [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), I advise you read up on them. If you want to do a WWW request not in a Coroutine then you have to poll the `isDone` manually and proceed when completed.

To answer last question: Will the game freeze when creating an instance of the WWW class? - No. The class works asynchronously. You can use it in normal Update/Start etc. functions and inside Coroutines with yield.

Comment: A coroutine is the way to go, because you cannot guarantee the responsiveness of an external site.  Further, even with a responsive external site, network latency can add lots of time to a request especially if it isn't coded well.

Comment: That depends on the scenario. WWW class works asynchronously so it won't freeze the main game loop thread, unless you wrap it in a while(!isDone) loop.

Answer (score -2):

**if I make a WWW call and it takes several seconds to reply, doesn't the game freeze?**
Not, Game Will not be freez try this code and you will see that log **"after corou"** will show immediately even the picture is downloading.

```
public class WWWDemo : MonoBehaviour {
    bool b = true;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (b) {
            StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
            Debug.LogWarning("after corou");
        }

    }

    IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
    {
        b = false;
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
        string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
        Renderer render = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        render.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);

    }
}
```

but the execution of next line will definitely stop after  yield return www statement it will wait unitl the picture download while the rest events of Unity will execute **async**.

Consider below example as well separately. Start Event executes ones it will wait but update will run continuously.

```
 IEnumerator Start() { 
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
        string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
        Renderer render = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        render.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
        Debug.Log("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
    }
void Update()
    {
            Debug.Log("update is running while start is waiting for downloading");        
    }
```

Comment: Baffled as to why you're launching the coroutine and spamming the console on every single frame